How to toggle the LCD Back light when User button is pressed on STM32f407-disc1
I am little new to embedded, I want to toggle the LCD Backlight (16x2) when I press the blue button on STM32f407-disc1, but when i press it for an instant it turns off then again comes back. Am I missing some delay or do I need to do it other way.
void btn_Task(void *pvParameters)
{
    uint8_t lcd_on = 1;
    while(1){

        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, BTN_PIN) && lcd_on)
        {
           HD44780_NoBacklight();
           lcd_on = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            HD44780_Backlight();
            lcd_on = 1;
        }
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(50));
    }
}

Desired result should be -

It should not toggle on and off back light upon holding the button and register it as a click untill released.
Once the switch is pressed back light should change its state for infinitely if not toggled again.

Is something wrong in the logic or some delay is missing to make sure user has released the button when processing the logic.

Your logic seems like it would constantly toggle the backlight on and off if you hold the button down.

@pmacfarlane yes its constantly toggling the back light on and off.
I need to add a logic  to register it one click until switch is released, thinking to add a variable that hold previous button state with a little delay.

You could simply remove the && lcd_on)from if ( .HAL_GPIO_ReadPin...)

@jeb I want to make the logic to toggle the back light when pressed once, the logic you are suggesting will make it so that it turns off back light as long I keep the button pressed.

To realize the toggling effect, your task needs to detect the change of the button state. For this it needs to remember the state of the button during the previous loop.
I'm assuming that the pin is low when the button is pressed. Otherwise, adjust the assignment.
To take button bounce into account, the task delays each loop by 50ms. There is no need for "sophisticated" debouncing logic, as such a sample rate is low enough to "jump over" the bouncing of most buttons, and is at the same time fast enough for the users.
void btn_Task(void *pvParameters)
{
    bool is_lcd_on = false;
    bool was_button_pressed = false;

    for (;;) {
        bool is_button_pressed = !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, BTN_PIN);

        if (is_button_pressed && !was_button_pressed) {
            is_lcd_on = !is_lcd_on;
            if (is_lcd_on) {
                HD44780_Backlight();
            } else {
                HD44780_NoBacklight();
            }
        }
        was_button_pressed = is_button_pressed;

        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(50));
    }
}


Thanks @the-busybee , In my logic I was not checking else part correctly as it has to be also checked within button click logic.
